# convert UTC time to date time format in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How to convert UTC time into date time format in flex. I am using sdk 3.5. for example I have current date time in UTC format as 1309522586000 (milliseconds) and I want to convert it to friday jul 1 2011. How can I do this??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using a UNIX timestamp that you are retrieving from your server, first you will have to multiply it by 1000.

This is because UNIX timestamps are expressed in seconds whereas ActionScript timestamps are expressed in milliseconds.

You can create a date from your timestamp as follows:

```
var myDate:Date = new Date(1309522586000);
```

Next, you create a formatDate function that you call with myDate as parameter:

```
    <fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <mx:DateFormatter id="myDF" formatString="EEEE MMM D YYYY"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function formatDate(date:Date):void{
            trace(myDF.format(date));
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Notice that I am using a dateformatter to format the date correctly.

More about DateFormatter and possible formats here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html

Cheers